# Set a Title for a jPanel on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I'm new to programming and I have a question about the window builder. I searched online looking for a way to set a title for a jPanel and not  a Jframe, and all what I found was to use for the Jframe `setVisible`. I  don't know if there is a way to set a title for jpanel. I need the user to always see which screen he accessed. I'm using eclipse java language. Please help

Comment: There is no built-in title on JPanels (that I know of). I've needed this a couple of times so I just made a `TitledPanel` that extended `JPanel`, then overrode the `paintComponent` method to paint the title at the top.

Comment: I answered my question so basically what I did is that I added a new border and added a title

Answer (score 5):

This is What I did

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

String title = "A titled border";
Border border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title);
mainPanel.setBorder(border);
```

Comment: I've tweaked your code a little bit to make it more readable.

Comment: Thank you ! @BrandonIbbotson

Comment: I got "error: cannot find symbol" around "Border" so I must add "import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;" and replace "Border border" by "TitledBorder border= BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("A titled border");"